# Multiple NSMutableDictionary objects created from single NSDictionaryObject showing same value

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an **inputArray** with below values:

```
@[@“one”,@“two”,@“three”,@“four,@“five”];
```

I have a plist file with below key values:

```
<dict>
    <key>displayProperties</key>
    <dict>
        <key>leftPadding</key>
        <integer>0</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>displayValues</key>
    <dict>
        <key>percentageValueKey</key>
        <string>percentageValueKey</string>
        <key>subtitleText</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>actualValueKey</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>titleValue</key>
        <string>Title Value</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

From above plist I am creating a dictionary: **mappingDict**.

Now I am trying to perform below steps:

```
1.  Initialize an empty mutable array- finalArray.
2.  Iterate through each object in inputArray.
3.  Create mutableDictionary from mappingDict.
4.  Replace value of a key in mutableDictionary with currently iterated value in inputArray.
5.  Add the updated mutableDictionary to finalArray.
```

I have used below code for the same:

```
- (void)generateFinalPlist
{
    // populate final array
    NSMutableArray *finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

    [self.inputArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString* inputRecord, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.mappingDict];
        mutableDict[@"displayValues"][@"percentageValueKey"] = inputRecord;
        [finalArray addObject:mutableDict];
    }];

    // generating plist file
    [finalArray writeToFile:self.finalPlistPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Problem is:

Each of the object in finalArray is showing ‘five’ as object for ‘percentageValueKey’.

Please suggest, if I am doing anything wrong?

**Solved:**

Please check answer and comment added by Martin R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.mappingDict];
```

creates a new dictionary containing the keys and values of `self.mappingDict`, but it
does *not copy the values*, which means that

```
mutableDict[@"displayValues"]
```

still refers to the the value in `self.mappingDict` and you are modifying the same
dictionary in each step of the loop. Try

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.mappingDict
                                        copyItems:YES];
```

instead.

***Update***: This does also not work because `copyItems:YES` causes the subdirectories to be
*copied*, which makes them immutable. What you need is a "deep mutable copy" where
all subdirectories are also mutable.

But there is an easier solution. Instead of copying `self.mappingDict`, just re-read it
from the plist as a mutable dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:mappingPlistPath];
```

This gives you independent mutable dictionaries for each enumeration step in the loop.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I tried your suggestion.. but in that case I am getting this exception: -[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object :(

Comment: @Miraaj: How is `self.mappingDict` created?

Comment: it is created using below code:
NSString *mappingPlistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MappingPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
    self.mappingDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:mappingPlistPath];

Comment: @Miraaj: Try `NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:mappingPlistPath];` in the enumeration block, instead of copying `self.mappingDict` .

Comment: voila.. it worked.. to my surprise.. any ideas.. why so?

Comment: @Miraaj: I will update the answer and try to explain!

Comment: ok... waiting for your updated answer.. it will be helpful :)